# How to show a div and the current link active after page reload jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I want to show a div and a link active which is clicked after page reload.  Initially class active is called to first link and div is hidden.

I checked everything I could think of, but didn't get the solution as my code is not working after page reload.

Please see the html and jquery code:

```
<div class="sub-cols" style="display:none;">
    <div class="wraper-berkowits">
    <a class="active" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>products-for-sale/attachments.html">Attachments</a>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>products-for-sale/removal.html">Removal</a></li>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>products-for-sale/hair-loss-store.html">Hair Loss</a></li>
    <a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl() ?>products-for-sale/care-maintenance.html">Care &amp; maintenance </a>
    </div>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.menu:first-child').addClass('first'); 

    jQuery('li.last a').click(function() {  
        jQuery('.sub-cols').show();
        return false;
    }); 

    jQuery(".sub-cols a").click(function () {        
        jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 

    });
});
```

Please check the above code and advise me how to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

As from your comments the question is better understood now
As your need is to regain the state of the link even after the page reload.
I can provide you the hint of achieving it

There are two ways -
1) you can $_SESSION in php to store the link clicked and can have it display using jquery

2) Using javascript only - 
   use window.localStorage – stores data with no expiration date

When you need to set a variable that should be reflected in the next page(s), use:

```
var someVarName = "value";
localStorage.setItem("someVarName", someVarName);
```

In your code you can do something like this

```
jQuery(".sub-cols a").click(function () {
        localStorage.setItem("someVarName", jQuery(this).text());
        jQuery(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
    jQuery(".sub-cols").show();
```

And in any page (like when the page has loaded), get it like:

```
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
```

`.getItem()` will return `null` or the value stored.

for your example you can use like this

```
if(localStorage.getItem("someVarName")!=null){
        $('a').filter(function(){
                return this.innerHTML == localStorage.getItem("someVarName"); 
            }).css({background:"#F00"});
    }
```

I have provided an updated demo - http://jsfiddle.net/bvqnzuwa/3/
To test it click on any link and then reload the page. You will see a background color on the link you clicked even after page reload.

Comment: But initially div will not display and submenu will not show.When i clicked on menu first child then all submenu will show and when i clicked on any of the submenu then that link will be active and div will also display......but now initially link is shown active as well as display block as per your code..please see my code carefully

Comment: @Prince - the code you provided seems to be incomplete because in that there is no div with class 'menu' yet your jquery code uses it. Can you provide a demo like a have upto what have it working. This will help providing a solution

Comment: Actually its a default magento code where topmenu is coming from this <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?> and when i clicked last topmenu then this div will display block which i have given above and after that when i clicked on any of submenu, then in that redirected page i want this div to display block and want to add class active to that submenu which is clicked...............i hope now u have cleared

Comment: @Prince - check my updated answer and the updated demo link -  http://jsfiddle.net/bvqnzuwa/3/ To test it click on any link and then reload the page. You will see a background color on the link you clicked even after page reload.

Comment: first time div should be hidden but here in first time also it is showing

Comment: @price - yes , i have provided you the logic that you can use in your own code scenario, your main need is to remember the state of the link that was activated/clicked after the page reload and i have provided the demo for the same. You must utilise it as per your code. the solution provides you the way of doing it. Also if you remove this line 'jQuery(".sub-cols").show();' all links will be hidden , the demo is made with what information is provided.